# Contrapositive form of a lemma including the term "general"

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, logic, terminology

[image]

In the above Lemma I just  want  the  contrapositive form of  item c) can somebody help me? sorry  if it  is a very easy  question but  I have  different opinions  about  the correct  contrapositive  form, so now i'm hesitating. Thank you!!!

Comment: Perhaps also offer the differing opinions that you mention, so that answers can be more customised/targeted rather than having to second-guess. For what it's worth, I second IsAdisplayName's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will first help to reword the sentence. The problem here is that there is a little ambiguity. There are two ways this sentence could be interpreted:

For all curves $C\in|L|$, if $CH_0(S)_{hom}\to Alb S$ is not an isomorphism, then $\ker j_*$ is countable.

or

If we have that,for all curves $C\in|L|$, $CH_0(S)_{hom}\to Alb S$ is not an isomorphism, then its the case that $\ker j_*$ is countable.

The first sentence is universally quantified while the second sentence is an implication with a universally quantified antecedent. From the context, I think the author means the first sentence. This sentence has the logical form $\forall x (P(x)\to Q(x))$. This is not an implication statement so it does not have a proper contrapositive. However, it is not to hard to prove that $\forall x (P(x)\to Q(x))$ is logically equivalent to $\forall x (\neg Q(x)\to \neg P(x))$.

So, your contrapositive should be $\forall C\in|L|, if \ker j_*$ is not countable then $CH_0(S)_{hom}\to Alb S$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you  very  much!  you  help me a lot :D!